# Interpreting where I would find the output files in Magento - templates

Tags: magento

I am a few weeks into using Magento, and this is a URL for which I'm trying to track the output file (I believe it would be a .phtml file):

```
http://mytest.shopland.com/smi130495/catalog/category/view/s/his-jewelry/id/312834/
```

the first parameter smi130495 is the store parameter, and obviously the last two are a name-value pair for the category.  I'm pretty sure we have NOT touched core, so there might be files in local.  However I'm also aware that there is a `skin` folder.  Does anyone have a suggestion of how to interpret it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably help you a lot to read [an article about how Magento routing works](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_standard_router), but I will explain briefly what your URL means:

`smi130495`: As you stated, this is your store code. Since Magento can support multiple tiers of websites/stores, this is an optional piece that depends on your setup.

`catalog/category/view`: This is the routing information (module, controller, action). This gets translated into a dispatch of  `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction()` found in the file `app/code/core/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php`.

`s/his-jewelry`: You are correct that this is where the params begin. This looks like a search term being passed from search results.

`id/312834`: This is the category ID that will be loaded by the dispatched controller action.

Knowing this information is the first clue to finding the code that will be used to create your output, but there is much more that goes into the rendering of the final output. It would be too long to explain everything here that can impact output since, for example, Magento uses an intermediate XML-based layout layer of “blocks” that in turn make use of templates to render specific pieces of content on the page.

However, I can point you to the main template for your route `app/design/frontend/$package/$theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`, which gets added to the layout like this in `app/design/frontend/$package/$theme/layout/catalog.xml`:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
</reference>
```

Hope that helps you some.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento `.phtml` files are inside :

**Admin panel files** : `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template`

**Frontend files** : `/app/design/frontend/default/{theme name}/template`

Like in query you are searching for `category/view` file

```
app/design/frontend/default/{theme name}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier, you can use several tools. Finding Templates in Magento sometimes is alot of work. Template Hints are a good way to find templates quicker. You can enable template-hints in the Magento backend in the Configuration under System->Development. In case you want a better solution with template hints, you can use this module from AOE:

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints

Hope this helps, regard, David